# How do I make my products on the homepage responsive?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, css, responsive, theme-twenty-seventeen

I am working in twenty seventeen theme. I have added products on the homepage using woocommerce's Products by category block. I first set the number of products per row to 4 products it is displayed perfectly on desktop view. The problem starts when the view is switched. When I saw the same page in mobile it did show all the products but damaged the view. Add to cart buttons were on each other and when I removed those button it still stayed same. The page shows images but it starts horizontal scrolling. Is there any way to set the products dynamically so that it shows 4 products in desktop view and 2 in mobile view? Please advice

Comment: you need to add css for those in required views.

Comment: Yep that might work but i am completely new to this how and where do i add the css so that it stays there until woocommerce plugin is there regardless of the theme